# How can I match atomic elements and their amounts in regex with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to make a tool to parse atomic elements from a formula

so say I started with `Ba(Co3Ti)2 + 3BrH20` I would first want to parse each compound in the formula, which is easy enough with `let regions = str.replace(/\s/g, '').split(/\+/g);`

Now for each compound, I want to identify each element and its numerical "amount"
so for the example above, for the first compound, Id want an array like this:

```js
[
 "Ba",
 [
  "Co3",
  "Ti"
 ],
 "2"
]
```

and if finding sub-compounds within parenthesis isnt possible, then I could work with this:

```js
[
 "Ba",
 "(Co3",
 "Ti)",
 "2"
]
```

Is this possible with regex?
This is what I've come up with in a few minutes..

```js
        let compounds = str.replace(/\s/g, '').split(/\+/g);
        for (var r = 0; r < compounds.length; ++r) {
            let elements = compounds[r]
        }
```

Comment: Maybe `str.match(/\(?(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\d+)\)?/g)` will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thats perfect, it fits all my test cases for the second array option, do you mind adding it as an answer?

Comment: Not part of your question but is this `3BrH20` supposed to be `3BrH2O` - `0` vs `O` or `o` makes a difference in regex

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, I probably just accidentally typed it like that, my bad, but 20 is a valid number, as there can be 20 hydrogen atoms in the formula for example (It doesn't necessarily have to be a real compound with real elements, as long as its parsed correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
str.match(/\(?(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\d+)\)?/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l63joa/1). *Details*:

- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\d+)` - either of the two options:

  - `[A-Z][a-z]*\d*` - an uppercase letter, then zero or more lowercase letters and then zero or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = 'Ba(Co3Ti)2';
const re = /\(?(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\d+)\)?/g;
let compounds = str.match(re);
console.log(compounds);
```

Comment: On a side note, this even works with multicharacter theoretical elements like Uup and Uub, which is a nice touch